# .net performance counter - Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time

Tags: .net, performancecounter

During performance testing, I found that the values of `Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time` are greater than 100. Some values are

```
237.1436486
312.5338052
341.2373994
264.4097661
191.6237736
```

I thought this value represents the CPU usage by w3wp process. I don't understand why the value is greater than 100%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have multiple cores it can go over 100, it's the sum of the processor usage for *each* processor (core, or virtual core) so over 100 is normal (`100*numberOfCores` is the nax).

Use the `Process(w3wp_Total)` version of the counter if you want the overall CPU %, this caps out at 100.

Comment: Hey, thanks. That makes sense, I will look for the counter you mentioned

Comment: Is there such a counter? The only one I know, other than "Process(w3wp)" would be "Process(_Total)", which of course is the sum for all processes. Personally, I simply did a ("Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time" / Environment.ProcessorCount) when having that problem.

Comment: I didn't find counter Process(w3wp_Total) but I considered doing the same ("Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time" / Environment.ProcessorCount) Thanks!

Comment: So how do you get the number of cores?  For instance, on my machine the Environment.ProcessorCount reads 2, but I'm getting up to 800% cpu usage returned from the performance counter.

Answer (score 5):

As Nick Craver already said, it is the combined value of all processors (logical or physical). To get a value between 0% and 100% simply divide it by the numbers of processors (e.g. `Environment.ProcessorCount`, assuming that you want to do it in .NET code).