# PerfMon and w3wp?

Tags: iis, perfmon, w3wp

I'm looking at "Process:w3wp*:% Processor Time" in PerfMon and am struggling to follow something.  I have traces running for w3wp and then w3wp#1 - w3wp#6, which are the six sites running on the server.

w3wp's trace doesn't appear to be related to the total of #1-#6 ?

e.g.
'#1 can have a %Processor higher than w3wp, and conversely w3wp can have near 100% when ALL the other %'s are very low.

I'm trying to find a performance bottleneck in our server and the obvious one is that the CPU tops out.  We are going to add another CPU (as it's on VM) but I'd like to try to understand what I am looking at...and what can be done to alleviate the issue?

Why is w3wp often close to 100% even though the individual sites are very low?  What might be causing w3wp to be so high if its not a particluar site?

ps.  If anyone has a way I can save an image here I can post the graph. TY
pps. IIS7 on Win2008.

Comment: Answered in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712782/net-performance-counter-processw3wp-processor-time

Comment: @GeoffreyMcGrath: please make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) in this thread: [.net performance counter - Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712782/net-performance-counter-processw3wp-processor-time)